# Steps for how to install QT, PyQT, and PySide on OS X Snow Leopard

Tags: python, macos, pyqt, py2app, pyside

I've had some problems installing QT on Snow Leopard and I'm hoping that I can benefit from someone else who's been in this position. :)

I'm assuming that I'll need to use a version of python that's not included with SL... be it from homebrew, macports, python.org, etc.

Can anyone give me some simple steps to follow to get QT, PyQT, and PySide installed? Bonus points for an example of how to setup a project to use py2app with all this.

Thanks! :)

Comment: Macports have most python versions. Is there a constraint in using macports?

Comment: No, but I don't have a problem installing python, just QT and friends.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to try out PySide, you can follow these steps:

http://blogger-mikael.blogspot.com/2010/09/compiling-pyside-for-qt-47-on-os-x.html

Answer (score 0):

Just use a binary distribution of PyQt + Qt + Python for OS X, and then install PySide manually.  For example, there's: http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt-mac/files/ , but it appears that the associated web site has vanished.

Just wondering though, why would you use both PyQt and PySide?

Comment: I don't necessarily need both. I was just curious in case I wanted to use one instead of the other.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install QT on Snow Leopard, this might help you...

According to [this bug report](https://bugreports.qt.nokia.com/browse/QTBUG-23157), the 4.8.0 release was bundled for OS X Lion only. Using the 4.8.0 release will result in errors like:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _kCFWebServicesProviderDefaultDisplayNameKey
Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/QtWebKit.framework/Versions/4/QtWebKit 
Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
```

In other words, you will need to use the 4.7.0 release until this is remedied. Homebrew is referencing 4.8.0, so you'll have to use the standalone installer. Here is the link for the [QT 4.7.0 Snow Leopard installer](http://get.qt.nokia.com/qt/source/qt-mac-opensource-4.7.0.dmg).

In regards to PyQT and PySide, I can't help you there. I don't know anything about Python. =/

Answer (score 0):

It seems that regarding Qt 5.x on SL, you need to compile it.
[This page explains how to do so](https://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/24395/).

However, having first installed the latest XCode 3.2.6 on SL, the setup runs smoothly. It's only when running Qt Creator that a few error messages start to appear:

```
Symbol not found: _kCFWebServicesProviderDefaultDisplayNameKey...
Plugin initialization failed...
```